# Loopback data denormalization

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have 2 models. One is an `Article (content, category)`, and the other is `Category (id, name)`.

In Article I have defined relation to Category.

```
"categories": {
  "type": "hasOne",
  "model": "Category",
  "foreignKey": "category"
}
```

I insert new Product with category id in category field.

Now, when I get the Articles over REST API I would like to receive category name instead of category Id.
I wanted to figure it out based on [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+model+relations), but failed.

I use MySQL relational DB.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the include filter
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter

In your case:

```
/articles?filter[include]=categories
```